# How to stop random number from regenerating?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a kid's number guessing game where a random number (between 1 and 50) is generated and you have to keep guessing the number until you find that generated number. You receive feedback about whether your guess is too high or too low to better inform your guess. Below is the code I've come up with, but the problem is, I can't seem to pinpoint the random number. It seems as if the number is regenerated with every guess. How can I make it so that the same number is used for every guess until guessed correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id ="game" action="javascript:void(checkGuess())">
        <p class="owlOne">I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 50.</p>
        <br class="clear" />
        <p class="owlTwo"><input id="guess" type="text"><input id="button" type="submit" value="Guess!"></p>
        <br class="clear" />
        <p class="owlOne"><span id="response">Can you guess what it is?</span></p>
    </form>

<script>
function checkGuess() {
    var guess = Number(document.getElementById('guess').value); // Assigns guessed number to variable.
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1); // Generates a random number between 1 and 50.

    // Guessed number is correct.
    if (guess == number) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML= "Congratulations, you guessed correctly!";
    }

    // Guessed number is within 5 above.
    else if (guess > number && guess <= number+5) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML= "You're so close! Just a little bit lower.";
    }

    // Guessed number is within 5 below.
    else if (guess < number && guess >= number-5) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML= "You're so close! Just a little bit higher.";
    }

    // Guessed number is at least 1, but more than 5 below.
    else if (guess < number-5 && guess >= 1) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML= "Too low! Guess again.";
    }

    // Guessed number is no more than 50, but less than 5 above.
    else if (guess > number+5 && guess <= 50) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML= "Too high! Guess again.";
    }

    // Guessed number is not within the 1 - 50 range.
    else {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML= "Remember, the number I'm thinking of is between 1 and 50.";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess that's "1 and 50 inclusive"? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
```

**outside** the function. Then the number will be generated only on page load, not every time the function is called.

`number` will become a global variable and also be accessible inside the function.

Comment: What's the fun in trying to guess a number that stays the same? I think the game as it is now is *way* more challenging :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Math.random() * 50 + 1` if `50` is in range? Since `Math.random() * 50` will always be less than 50 'cos `Math.random()` never returns 1.

Comment: @RobG: Not according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Example:_Using_Math.random *edit:* Oh, maybe this is only if max is not included. I guess you are right!

Comment: I understood it as "1 to 50 inclusive", otherwise it's 1 to 49 inclusive, but not clear from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you're calling the function it is redefining number to be a new Random number.  If you move the declaration outside the function than it won't be redefined every time you call checkGuess;

Your code should look something like

```
 var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1); 

   function checkGuess() {
      // code
   }
```

However you should note, this puts number in the global scope, you can also do something like

```
var checkGuess = (function(number) {
   return function(){
      // code that was in checkGuess(){

   } 
})(Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
```

what this does is it returns your checkGuess function to the variable but now that code has access to the number variable because it is inside a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: Every function JavaScript is a closure. If you are referring to `(function() {...}(...))` as the closure, then you are technically correct, but that function wouldn't have to be a closure for this to work. The important thing here is that *invoking* the function creates a new scope.

Comment: @FelixKling—don't agree every function is a closure. "Closure" isn't defined in ECMA-262 regarding functions and scope, so the definition becomes moot. [A closure](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) normally requires access to variables after their execution context has finished executing (e.g. emulation of private members). Accessing variables in an outer execution context that is still executing is just resolution on a stock scope chain, a closure gives access to variables that persists from a previous scope chain, not just the one created by the current execution context chain.

Comment: @RobG: I think there are two ways define closures. One is the one you mentioned, and the other is that every function that has free variables is a closure. I decided to accept the explanation provided by Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29. Have a look at the first sentence, it fits perfectly for JS functions. We can agree to disagree? :)

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you're right that the important part is number run before the function invocation. All I'm saying is that creating a closure prevents you from polluting the global scope, which is generally a best practice. A generic variable name like number which could easily be overwritten and cause all types of problems.